# How to parse only the output to be as yes or no all the rest ignore?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

How can i only output that yes or no by skiping anything?

```
$ pactl list sources | grep -A 6 "Name: alsa_input.usb.analog-mono" | tail -n 1 | perl -p -i -e 's/.+\\s(yes|no)$/$1/'


Mute: no
```

insead show only: `no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `perl` expression is broken. Observe:

```
$ echo "Mute: no" | perl -p -i -e 's/.+\\s(yes|no)$//'
Mute: no
```

It doesn't do anything! The reason it doesn't do anything is because nothing is matching. Why not? Because you unnecessarily escaped `\s`. The correct expression should be `s/.+\s(yes|no)$/$1/`. Notice the single `\` preceding `s`.

With this new expression we get:

```
$ echo "Mute: no" | perl -p -i -e 's/.+\s(yes|no)$/$1/'
no
$ echo "Mute: yes" | perl -p -i -e 's/.+\s(yes|no)$/$1/'
yes
```

Note that this still doesn't do what you want, because if nothing matches, the whole line is emitted as is. For example:

```
$ echo "Mute: monkies" | perl -p -e 's/.+\s(yes|no)$/$1/'
Mute: monkies
```

While this can probably solved with a more complex regular expression, I will not do so. Instead I will quote the following:

> Sometimes when people see a problem, they think to themselves "I
>   know, I will use regex." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -M5.010 -ne 'say $1 if m/\s(yes|no)$/i'
```

Comment: Can't open perl script "say $1 if m/\\s(yes|no)$/i": No such file or directory

Comment: @YumYumYum, as part of a pipeline, `-i` makes no sense, otherwise it's sucking up the `'e'` part of the switch as the extension, so it doesn't recognize the next argument as code.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
LANG=C pactl list sources | perl -0 -lne'print $1 if /Name: alsa_input.usb.analog-mono\n(?:\N+\n){5}\s+Mute: (yes|no)/ms'
```

But you need to parse this properly, you cannot rely on the Mute line always coming exactly 6 lines after.

Answer (score 0):

from perl perspective:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/.+\\s(yes|no)$/$1/is'
```

Please insert the raw input and what do you want achive (expected output)

Comment: Shows still `Mute: no` instead `no` only.